# Exit Silverlight OOB application

Tags: silverlight, exit, out-of-browser

I've built a small Out-Of-Browser Silverlight 4 application on which I have an exit button. Clicking on this button is supposed to deliver the same behaviour as clicking close (X button) on the upper right corner - close (exit) application. But I can't figure out how this is done... I've already tried suggestions like **Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()** calling from my button's Click event,  but it won't work-nothing happens.
Note: Maybe important - executing that line ( **Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()** ) from In-Browser mode generates the following exception> *"Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications."* but I suppose that's normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just ran into solution to this 'issue': In order to use **Application.Current.MainWindow.Close()** to exit your OOB app, it is necessary to enforce **ElevatedPermissions** within your application's Out-Of-Browser settings. Hope this will save lots of someone's time...